# How to draw the transfer function of an RC circuit using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

If I have an RC circuit with transfer function `1/(1+sRC)` how do I draw the transfer function using MATLAB?

```
Num2=[1];
Den2=[R*C 1];
RCcirc=tf(Num2,Den2);
```

How do I declare the R and the C so that there are no errors?

Comment: Are you asking how to [plot a function in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html)?

Comment: yes , but first i need to know how to declare the RC trasfer function using matlab

Comment: @Shadi: Show us what you've tried. We won't do your homework.

Comment: ok
i edited the question

Comment: Wouldn't R and C just be fixed numbers? What error are you getting?

Comment: No i have to output the transfer function in terms of s and R and C as shown above

Answer (score 2):

`tf` is the wrong tool for plotting the transfer function. Try these instead:

1. Use [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) to generate a range of values for `s`. Give `R` and `C` reasonable values of your choice.
2. Read up on [arithmetic operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) in MATLAB, especially `./`
3. Look at how to use [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) and familiarize yourself with the command using some simple examples from the docs.

With these you should be able to plot the transfer function in MATLAB :)

Comment: I cannot use values for R and C thats the thing i need the transfer function in terms of R and C and S

Comment: can you just please tell me how to write the variables of R and C without intializing them with values so that the transfer function appears as 1/(1+sRC)

Comment: While `tf` does not plot a transfer function, it is the right way to go when you are working with transfer functions. There are lots of functions which will take a `DynamicSystem` object (like a `tf` system) and plot e.g. the bode plot, nyquist plot, ...

What you are suggesting will lead to a frequency response function (FRF), while it provides good visualization of a transfer function (TF), it is not the same. In a TF the `s` (or `z`, ...) remains a free variable, in an FRF this not the case. The FRF is the evaluation of a TF in a set of values for `s=jw` (or `z=e^jw`, ...).

Comment: @Egon: I don't know if you were replying to me or to Shadi, but you're correct. I know what `tf` does, but that is definitely not what the OP needs here. The confusion seems more fundamental and hopefully your explanation helped him. I stopped replying after OP became confrontational and abusive (comments deleted).

Comment: @yoda: I was replying to you indeed. I agree with you that the OP's problem probably lies at a more fundamental level, but we can both only guess what he actually needs. In any way, both your approach and mine require a substitution of the parameters `R` and `C` at some point, which he refuses to do.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand what transfer function you want. Without defined values of R and C you won't get any transfer function. Compare it to this, you want to plot a sine wave: `x = sin(w*t)`, I hope you can agree with me that you cannot plot such a function (including axes) unless I specifically say e.g. `t` is the time, ranging from 0 seconds to 10 seconds and `w` is a pulsation of 1 rad/s. It's exactly the same with your RC network: without any values, it is impossible for numerical software such as MATLAB to come up with a plot.

If you fill in those values, you can use th `tf` function to display the transfer function in whatever way you like (e.g. a bode plot).

On the other hand, if you just want the expression `1/(1+s*R*C)`, take a look at the symbolic toolbox, you can do such things there. But to make a plot, you will still have to fill in the `R` and `C` value (and even a value for your Laplace variable in this case).